# Stream interactive shell session with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, xtermjs

I have 3 components `device`, `server` and `frontend (admin)`.

#### Server

Starts socket.io server with 2 namespaces `/admin` and `/client`.
If socket from `/admin` namespace sends data, server passes it along to `/client` namespace. If socket from `/client` namespace sends data, server passes it along to `/admin` namespace.

```js
const io = require('socket.io');
const device = io.of('/device');
const admin = io.of('/admin');

device.on('connection', (socket) => {

  socket.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log("PASSING DATA FROM [DEVICE] TO [ADMIN]")
    admin.emit('data', data);
  })

});

admin.on('connection', (socket) => {

  socket.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log("PASSING DATA FROM [ADMIN] TO [DEVICE]")
    device.emit('data', data);
  });

});

io.listen(80);
```

#### Device

Uses `socket.io-client` to connect to `socket.io` server.
Starts interactive shell session using `node-pty`.

```js
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io('http://localhost:80/client');
const os = require('os');
const pty = require('node-pty');
const shell = os.platform() === 'win32' ? 'powershell.exe' : 'bash';

const ptyProcess = pty.spawn(shell, [], {
  name: 'xterm-color',
  cols: 80,
  rows: 30
});

socket.on('connect', () => {

});

// INPUT DATA
socket.on('data', (data) => {
  ptyProcess.write(data);
});

// OUTPUTING DATA
ptyProcess.onData = (data) => {
  socket.emit('data', data)
}
```

#### Frontend

Finally I have the frontend which uses `xterm.js` to create a terminal inside the browser. I am using `vue`. The browser client as well connects to `socket.io` server on the `/admin` namespace. Basically I have this :

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="terminal" ref="terminal"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { Terminal } from 'xterm';
import { FitAddon } from 'xterm-addon-fit';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

export default {
  mounted() {

    const term = new Terminal({ cursorBlink : true });
    term.open(this.$refs.terminal);

    const socket = io('http://localhost:80/admin');

    socket.on('connect', () => {

      term.write('\r\n*** Connected to backend***\r\n');
      term.onData((data) => {
        socket.emit('data', data);
      })

      socket.on('data', (data) => {
        term.write(data);
      });

      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        term.write('\r\n*** Disconnected from backend***\r\n');
      });

    });

  }
}
</script>
```

## Problem

❌ Starting the pty session seems to work, at least there are now errors reported. However it seems the `onData` listener callback is never fired, even when I `ptyProcess.write()` something.

❌ Getting input from `xterm` all the way to the device `ptyProcess.write` does not seem to work. I can see the data passed along through the socket.io sockets all the way to the device. But from there nothing happens. What do I miss ? Also I don't see my input in the `xterm` window as well.

Comment: This will not work with `child_process`, use `node-pty` instead to run the shell, it pipes the data through PTY/ConPty providing the needed bidirectional access and TTY abstraction.

Comment: Thanks @jerch ! I found out about `node-pty` pretty much at the same time I read your comment  haven't tried it yet but does look like it makes more sense to use it in this case.

Comment: Updated to use `node-pty` ... haven't had any luck yet :(

Comment: I dont quite understand your client/server separation. Normally `node-pty` should be called on server side / target machine (needs interfaces from the underlying OS). The shell you get is a real shell on that machine.

Comment: The client in that case would be an iot device like a raspberry pi which i do not have direct access of course.

Comment: "Client" is probably a bit misleading ... but the pty should run server side on the iot device (which is a client to our main server) thats why i called it client ... but lets call it device then .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching from `child_process` to using `node-pty` to create an interactive shell session I almost had it right. Following the `node-pty` documentation it marked the `on('data')` eventhandler as deprecated. Instead I should use `.onData` property of the process to register a callback. Like this:

```js
ptyProcess.onData =  function(data) {
  socket.emit('data', data);
};
```

But that didn't do anything. So I switched back to the depracated way of adding an event listener:

```js
ptyProcess.on('data', function(data) {
  socket.emit('data', data);
});
```

Now I have a working interactive shell session forwarded from a remote device through websocket inside my browser ✅.

**UPDATE** 
Did more digging for `onData` property. Realized it's not a property but a method so I used it wrong. This would be the prefered way :

```js
ptyProcess.onData(function(data) {
  socket.emit('data', data);
});
```

Which also works as expected